# USB communication in C#

Tags: c#, windows, usb, serial-communication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I connect to a USB webcam in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113426/how-do-i-connect-to-a-usb-webcam-in-net)

I just got a USB camera and have to write code in order to get the image/video stream.

What I'm not understanding is how to open the USB port like uart/rs232 and send/receive the data?

And one more thing, is what is HID (usb hid) and why we need it?

I found a couple of examples [here](http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm) but I'm not understanding the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Port Programming is what you after it.

check this link:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)

check this blog post for more detail : [developerfusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/)

Comment: yeah but does it work if i open the usb port and do send/recv?