# vb.net windows application barcode scanner

Tags: vb.net, webcam, barcode

I am creating a windows application which scans barcode and identifies the product. For it, I am planning to use a webcam temporarily. I want to know how can I interface my webcam with the application. The webcam is USB one.

The application is similar to the ones available these days on Smartphones.

Please help.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of **Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)**

Here are several resources which you can use.

[**How to use a web cam in C# with .NET Framework 4.0 and Microsoft Expression Encoder 4**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202464/How-to-use-a-WebCam-in-C-with-the-NET-Framework-4)

[**C# WebCam User Control Source**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markhsch/archive/2007/11/19/c-webcam-user-control-source.aspx)

[**How do I connect to a USB webcam in .NET?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113426/how-do-i-connect-to-a-usb-webcam-in-net)

or DirectShow.Net

[**Webcam using DirectShow.NET**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18511/Webcam-using-DirectShow-NET)

Comment: This is of course only half the solution because once you have acquired the image you have to then decode the barcode from it

Answer (score 5):

You can use either the WIA approach or the DirectShow, depending on your web cam driver. In both cases, unless you are very familiar with these 2 approaches, you might want to use a third-party library. We are using a third-party multimedia toolkit named leadtools to control our web cameras. You can check this [forum post](http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/10345/ShowPost.aspx) for further information.
Also, this toolkit supports reading barcodes. For more information, refer to this [Tutorial](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/to/leadtools.topics.barcode~ba.topics.readingbarcodes.html)