# Get connected Webcams in C#

Tags: c#, .net, camera, operating-system, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I connect to a USB webcam in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113426/how-do-i-connect-to-a-usb-webcam-in-net)

I'm developing .Net solution with C#.

In my application, I need to know whole connected Webcams or cams. And getting Inputs from these webcams. But main problem is connected webcam devices are unknown.

For example, if someone use my application on their computer, my application must scan all connected webcams and also should be ask to user which webcam user wants to use.it likes Skype does. Skype enables users to select webcam to use. And Skype get inputs from selected webcam.

How can scan webcams and get streams from that web cam?

Comment: Which API are you using to interact with your webcams, DirectShow or WIA? Also, if you are using a third-party SDK, such as [Dynamic .NET TWAIN](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/.Net-TWAIN-Scanner.aspx), there should be some properties to get the list of webcam/scanner drivers available on the computer.

Comment: @Windy the cost of Dymamic .NET TWAIN is 800 dollars. Are u crazy?

Comment: With WMI without the need for external libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452757/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-camera-devices-from-my-pc-c-sharp/62128539#62128539

Answer (score 1):

I would seggest to you to use AForge framework for this, it has all you need in very clean way: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/video.html

Comment: I have checked AForge and it seems that is possible to get the list of WebCams with their framework. So we have to install it and find C:\Program Files (x86)\AForge.NET\Framework\Samples\Video\Two Cameras Test  and then search for code:         // enumerate video devices
                videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection( FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice );