# How to get the built in Camera if more than one cameras are connected?

Tags: c#, camera, win-universal-app, uwp

In Universal Windows Apps with the following code snippet

```
var devices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

if (devices.Count < 1)
{
     return;
}

string deviceID = devices[0].Id;
```

I can get the cameras that are connected to my device. If there is more than one cameras, is there a way to explicitly get the built in camera and not a USB (or bluetooth or anything) connected one?

Comment: Also I noticed we have two tags with the same meaning so I put them both, a moderator should make them as synonyms

Comment: With WMI without the need for external libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452757/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-camera-devices-from-my-pc-c-sharp/62128539#62128539

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`EnclosureLocation.Panel` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.enclosurelocation.panel.aspx) to determine whether the camera you found is one that is built into the device. If the panel is `Unknown`, then it is an external camera. Note that there can be more than one built-in camera. (For example, some devices have both a front camera and a rear camera.)

Code inspired by [the Camera Starter Kit sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs):

```
// Attempt to get the back camera if one is available,
// but use any camera device if not.
var cameraDevice = await FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(
                             Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back); 

if (cameraDevice == null)
{
    // This device has no camera.
}
else if (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation == null ||
         cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel ==
                             Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Unknown) 
{ 
     // We have an external camera.
}
else
{
     // We have a built-in camera. The location is reported in
     // cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel.
}
```