# LibVLCSharp how to get list of webcams

Tags: c#, libvlcsharp

VLC GUI shows the list of available webcams, like `v4l2:///dev/video0`  and `v4l2:///dev/video1`, I am wondering is there a way to get a list of available webcams? what about their default resolution?

[image]

I tried this but `md.MediaList` is empty.

```
var mds = libVlc.MediaDiscoverers(MediaDiscovererCategory.Devices);
if (mds.Any(x => x.LongName == "Video capture"))
{
    var devices = mds.First(x => x.LongName == "Video capture");
    var md = new MediaDiscoverer(libVlc, devices.Name);
    foreach (var media1 in md.MediaList)
    {
       // Nothing ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MediaDiscoverer is empty because you never call **md.Start()**.
For more info, I found this really helpful: [/LibVLCSharp/MediaDiscoverer.cs](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/master/src/LibVLCSharp/MediaDiscoverer.cs)

That being said, I had no success using MediaDiscoverer to look for webcams myself.

If you don't insist on using LibVLC, you can list all camera devices without any third party software: [How can I get a list of camera devices from my PC C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452757/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-camera-devices-from-my-pc-c-sharp)

from Francesco Bonizzi:

```
public static List<string> GetAllConnectedCameras()
{
    var cameraNames = new List<string>();
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE (PNPClass = 'Image' OR PNPClass = 'Camera')"))
    {
        foreach (var device in searcher.Get())
        {
            cameraNames.Add(device["Caption"].ToString());
        }
    }

    return cameraNames;
}
```