# accessing a USB camera without drivers using WPF and C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, camera, usb

Hi I am using a USB camera which has a button to capture images. I have embedded in my application the code to capture images via web camera which is working fine. I have attached another camera via USB for some specific reasons. I don't have the drivers of the attached USB camera. Is there a way to access the USB camera without drivers in c# . Iam using WPF for the purpose of UI

Comment: Does the OS recognise the camera? Are you asking for a generic way to access a webcam? In what OS?

Comment: Yes Alex, Os recognizes the camera as a usb peripheral. i am using widows 8.

Comment: Looked @ WIA? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113426/how-do-i-connect-to-a-usb-webcam-in-net

Comment: Yes I have gone through it , the WIA, my problem is that when i have a web cam connected to my pc, it is working absolutely fine. Then i connect another camera(to be used for medical purposes) which seems to be getting detected, but no display which i think is mainly due to driver reasons. Is there a way to access it without drivers?